# Java Script Pop Up box when Multiple User selects same Row in Gridview

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with many rows with a SELECT link on the first row. The gridview is used by many users at a time. When two users click on the same row at the same time a pop up box will display to one of the clerks saying that one items was chosen by another user.

I have this javascript code below but the pop up box is not showing.

```
 protected void gvTypes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (condition)
     {                   
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
           sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
           sb.Append("alert('");
           sb.Append("The following item has been chosen by another user. Please choose another one. \\n\\n" + row.Cells[3].Text + "\\n");
           sb.Append("')};");
           sb.Append("</script>");
           ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());
      }
  }
```

Gridview

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>                      
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvTypes" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
                        Width="688px" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvTypes_SelectedIndexChanged"
                        Font-Size="14px" PageSize="11" DataKeyNames="TicketId, TicketNumber, LinkedTicketId"
                        OnRowCommand="gvMain_RowCommand" OnPageIndexChanging="gvMain_PageIndexChanging">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True"/>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="TicketId" HeaderText="Ticket Id" SortExpression="TicketId"
                                Visible="false">
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="TicketNumber" HeaderText="Ticket #Id" SortExpression="TicketNumber"
                                Visible="false">
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                        </Columns>
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TimerGVMain" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" Interval="5200" runat="server" OnTick="TimerGVMain_Tick">
            </asp:Timer>
```

Comment: Are you getting errors?

Comment: Have you tried `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()` instead? Also bare in mind the page (or part of it - UpdatePanel / AJAX) needs to be posted back for the script to run.

Comment: @TryingToImprove I am not getting errors.

Comment: @MelanciaUK yes the gridview is in update panel that updates every second.

Comment: Then you should register the script to the `ScriptManager` related to this `UpdatePanel`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Does your code get written to the page? What if there is an inverted comma in the text?

Comment: @MelanciaUK thats what I did look at my code.

Comment: `ClientScript.Register...` is one thing, `ScriptManager.Register...` is another. If the script you're registering is supposed to run in an `UpdatePanel` refresh, you need to use the second. If it's related to the whole page refresh, the first.

Comment: @MelanciaUK it gives me "No overload for method 'RegisterClientScriptBlock' takes 3 arguments

Comment: ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Info1", "alert('Someone else is using this item.');", true);

Comment: The number of arguments are different. Check the link to the MSDN in my previous comments.

Comment: @MartinSmellworse what is "Info1" for

Comment: @MelanciaUK pop up box does not show up still.

Comment: Info1 is just a name - so if you register multiple script blocks they register separately. If you write the same block with the same name it will only get written once. You can call it anything you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so sure about the rest of your code, but based on what's in the question, if you register the script to the `ScriptManager`, it should work:

```
protected void gvTypes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (condition)
    {                   
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // Using function pageLoad() to execute the script 
        // whenever the page is fully or partially loaded (AJAX).
        sb.Append("function pageLoad() {");
        sb.Append("alert('");
        sb.Append("The following item has been chosen by another user. Please choose another one. \\n\\n" + row.Cells[3].Text + "\\n");
        sb.Append("')}");
        // UpdatePanel1 needs to be replaced with your UpdatePanel ID.
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(UpdatePanel1, typeof(UpdatePanel), "alert", sb.ToString(), true);
    }
}
```

[MSDN ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**EDIT**

You can change your markup slightly, by moving the `Timer` to be inside the `UpdatePanel`:

```
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" Interval="5200" runat="server" OnTick="TimerGVMain_Tick"></asp:Timer>
</ContentTemplate>
```

And removing the `Triggers`:

```
<!--<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TimerGVMain" />
</Triggers>-->
```

**EDIT 2**

Or, you can leave the `Timer` where it is, and change the `Triggers`, by adding the `EventName` for the `Timer`:

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TimerGVMain" EventName="Tick" />
</Triggers>
```

Comment: Not working. This was working for a minute then it doesnt work anymore. ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Info1", "alert('Someone else is using this item.');", true);

Comment: What do you mean with `was working for a minute` exactly? The popup appeared once and nevermore? Some other behavior? Also, did you try `RegisterStartupScript`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Another detail. The control that's firing up the `UpdatePanel` refresh (a timer maybe?) needs to be inside the `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: Timer cant go inside an Update Panel it will throw an error.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the `GridView` markup.

Comment: Markup is up check it out

Comment: I took out the triggers and moved the timer and nothing. Do you think If I use onclick event for the select it will work?

Comment: I'm getting confused here. I just created a new project on Visual Studio here to test a similar piece of code (as I've not been working with WebForms for a while) and it just worked. There must be something else going on.

Comment: When I click select all it does is highlight the row.

Comment: It works! I had a method that writes to a table and it wouldn't let me write duplicates entries. When I clicked on the same ones it was already in the table causing the pop up to not show up.